# has_many :through with has_and_belongs_to_many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, model-associations

In Rails - what is the effect of using has_many :through with has_and_belongs_to_many?
Consider having two models - Posts and Tags which have a many-to-many relationship as indicated below:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tag
  has_many :tags,  :through => posts_tag
end

class PostsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

The reason I use `has_and_belongs_to_many` is because a `tag` belongs to many posts.

I did look into the [Rails Association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and see that they don't mention this case for a many-to-many relationship.  I, however, did try this and running it in Rails didn't yield any behavior and from the small test database that I built, also seemed to return the correct results for `post.tags` and `tag.posts` - where `post` and `tag` refer to an instance of the `Post` and `Tag` models respectively.

Is this correct usage or does it have any side affects that I am not aware of?  Also, if it is correct, is this the Rails way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `has_and_belongs_to_many` only when you're setting a many-to-many association (in other words, when the other side also has `has_and_belongs_to_many`). That is the meaning of this association.

You should have

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
end

class PostsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :posts_tags
end
```

Notice that I used the plural, `post_tags` (because this is the correct way).

If you have the situation like in your comment, you should have a

```
belongs_to :post_tag
```

in your `Post` model, and

```
has_many :posts
```

in your `PostTag` model.

You may ask now: "Why should I use `belongs_to :post_tag`? It doesn't **belong** to a tag, it **has** a tag. So, shouldn't I use `has_one :post_tag`?". This was also my question at first, but then I figured that it Rails cannot always perfectly suit the english language. You need the `post_tag_id` column on your `post`, and `belongs_to` expects exactly that. On the other hand, `has_one` would expect that a column named `post_id` is present on the **other** side, that is in your `post_tag`. But this would be impossible, because `post_tag` has many `posts` (not only one), so the `post` IDs cannot be held in `post_tags`.

**Update**:
The difference between associations are only in the methods you are provided and options you can pass in (the one explained in the Rails guide on associations). For example, `has_one` and `belongs_to` have the same methods:

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
```

But, for example, methods `association=` and `create_association` imply different things concerning where the foreign key should be (like I explained above).

`has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many` probably don't have anything different in their methods, but they differ in the options you can pass. For example, you can pass in

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

on the `has_many` association, but you can't pass it to a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, because that wouldn't make sense, since it implies a many-to-many association; if a parent record is destroyed, child records can still be connected with other records, so they shouldn't also be destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I guess the part where you said "Rails cannot always perfectly suit the English language" is what I was really looking for :P

Given that some common operations were working with a `has_many :through`  and `has_and_belongs_to_many`, from a purely pedagogical perspective it would be interesting to know if that has any side-affects.  I understand that's not the correct way of using it though.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure of the exact effects of having a `has_many :through` on one side of a relationship and a `has_and_belongs_to_many` on the other side, I do know that the more correct way, would be to use a reversed `has_many :through` like so:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tag
  has_many :posts,  :through => posts_tag
end
```

Keeping the other relationships the same.

Comment: How about the side-affects of using `has_one` one side of a relationship and `has_and_belongs_to_many` on the other side?  For instance in the examples above, if we were to say that each `post` can have at most one `tag`.  However, a `tag` would belong to many `posts`.

Comment: In that case you have the relation a bit backwards. Tag `has_many` Posts, and Posts `belongs_to` a Tag. Post would have `tag_id` on it, allowing for only a single tag. `has_and_belongs_to_many` is going to use a hidden join table that `has_many` won't be using.